# Why is constructed NSDate from components not same as components used as input?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, ios9, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to set a NSDate from components; the hour is the only thing that I need to actually set, the remainder is from current date.  This is my code:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

//  put in date with start time
int month = [components month];
int day = [components day];
int year = [components year];

[components setHour: startTime];
[components setMinute: 0];
[components setSecond: 0];
NSDate *startDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
```

This is the result from the console:

> Printing description of components:
>   
>       Calendar Year: 2015
>       Month: 10
>       Leap month: no
>       Day: 3
>       Hour: 1730
>       Minute: 0
>       Second: 0
>
> Printing description of startDate:
>   2015-10-25 15:57:12 +0000

Notice that the month and time have changed from what was supplied.  My question is why did it change (for future reference) and what do I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `startTime`? It appears to be `1730` which is probably not what you want. It should be a value in the range 0 - 23.

Comment: Yep...thanks Rick... re-write it as the answer if you want the points...  :D

SD